# Jenkins Build - Maven java not found

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins

I have simple Jenkins pipeline running maven build:

[image: Jenkins maven configuration]

My jdk configurations seems to be correct:

[image: Open JDK configuration]

However maven build ends with error:

**/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java: not found**

What is most weird, when I've added shell commands run before maven build:

```
ls -lrta /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java
chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java
/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -version
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java -version
```

I've got:

```
+ ls -lrta /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12328 Nov 30 18:13 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java
+ chmod 777 /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java
+ /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10, mixed mode)
+ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java -version
/tmp/jenkins9484991885087509801.sh: line 19: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java: not found
```

So:

1. ls correctly lists java execution file
2. same file could not be found when I run "/bin/java -version"

What is wrong here ?

For simple pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven 'Maven 3.9.0'
    jdk 'openjdk-19.0.2'
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn clean package'
      }
    }
    stage ('Deploy') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo 'Deploy'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting error:

```
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.9.0/bin/mvn: exec: line 195: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java: not found
```

Comment: Configure the path to maven on the buildagent configuration page

Comment: Maven is being found. For simple pipeline:
``` pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
    maven 'Maven 3.9.0'
    jdk 'openjdk-19.0.2'
  }
  stages {
    stage ('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'mvn clean package'
      }
    }
    stage ('Deploy') {
      steps {
        script {
          echo 'Deploy'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I am getting /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.9.0/bin/mvn: exec: line 195: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/openjdk-19.0.2/jdk-19.0.2/bin/java: not found

Comment: Maven depends on Java, same story, it should be configure in the buildagent. Usually maven can find java if JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME is set to the java installation path

Comment: Where can I find this buildagent configuration page ?

Comment: Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes and Clouds > [your build agent] > Configure > Node Properties > JDK_HOME=/opt/jdk/

But there are more places where you can configure maven to find your JDK. What works for you is dependent on so many factors. Cloudbees who maintains Jenkins has a 30 minute video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qx3XK82BZPk